# CSS3 : a div on text box

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox with having character limit box on it. What I want is. the text that is to be input should be upto the length of visible part of textbox.

I have tried this code.

```css
.add_caption_div input[type="text"] {
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid;
  width: 190px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
}
.add_caption_div .image_galley_char_limit_div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 31px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999999;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100001;
  background:#f6f8f8;
  top:-6px;
  right:51px;
}
.add_caption_div .form-control:focus {
  border: thin #66afe9 solid;
}
.add_caption_div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_caption_div" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="Enter Caption">
  <div class="image_galley_char_limit_div text-center">
  <span> 0/30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I type input then it goes behind the character_limit_div.

How can I prevent it?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Where is the characters limit of your textbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.add_caption_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
}
.add_caption_div input[type="text"] {
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid;
  width: 190px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
}
.add_caption_div .form-control {
  padding-right: 60px !important;
}
.add_caption_div .image_galley_char_limit_div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 31px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100001;
  top: 1px;
  right: -73px;
  background:#f6f8f8;
}
.add_caption_div .form-control:focus {
  border: thin #66afe9 solid;
}
.add_caption_div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_caption_div" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="Enter Caption">
  <div class="image_galley_char_limit_div text-center">
  <span> 0/30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can give `padding-right` for input, something like this:

```css
.add_caption_div input[type="text"] {
  border: thin #dee5e7 solid;
  width: 190px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
}
.add_caption_div .image_galley_char_limit_div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 31px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #999999;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100001;
  background:#f6f8f8;
  top:-6px;
  right:51px;
}
.add_caption_div .form-control:focus {
  border: thin #66afe9 solid;
}
.add_caption_div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.form-control{
   padding-right: 70px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_caption_div" >
  <input type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="Enter Caption">
  <div class="image_galley_char_limit_div text-center">
  <span> 0/30</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just one thing. if I resize my browser window. then will it be responsive?

Comment: depends on how you are handling the input while resizing. padding is inside the input, if input doesn't change it will be fine.